# How to send a mms without asking createchooser in android

Tags: android

I want to send a mms from my mobile without asking intent create chooser, i put my coding below, i did't add intent.createchooser in the coding but when i am running application it shows the create chooser dialog,

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent1.putExtra("address",to.getText().toString());
intent1.putExtra("sms_body",body);
intent1.setType("text/*");
startActivity(intent1);
```

tell me how to send a mms without asking createchooser

Answer (score 0):

Use `ACTION_SENDTO` and an `smsto:` `Uri` value specifying the phone number to send the SMS to, instead of `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: i changed to ACTION_SENDTO and an smsto: but still showing create chooser dialog, still no joy

Comment: @user1201450: That means there are multiple SMS clients on the device. Please allow the user to choose which SMS client the user wishes to employ.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "hi\nSend u Audio File.");
    sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
    sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
    sendIntent.putExtra("address", sender_num);
```